# Strange math addition

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

**If**

> 111 + 168 = 2001
>  211 + 606 = 1201
>  521 + 926 = 1501
>  889 +
>   816 = 9091
>  169 + 898 = 6551
>  869 + 168 = 6851
>  251 + 696 =
>   1211
>  951 + 998 = 2201
>  651 + 268 = 1501
>  191 + 598 =
>   9201
>  291 + 998 = 8201

**Then**

> 105 + 509 + 588 = ?

Comment: Do not think too far, this strange math have a very simple rule.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> 105 + 509 + 588 = 1661

The equations all make sense if:

> you look at them upside down! For instance, 111 + 168 punched into a calculator is actually 891 + 111 = 1002, which is 2001 upside down.

Comment: you are a bit mistype, 861 must be 891.  So what is the answer ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I was so caught up in getting it that I completely forgot to actually answer your question!

Comment: So $885+605+501=1991$ and the answer is  $1661$. Why 5 and 2 are not respectively swapped turning upside down?

Comment: @z100 If you punched 2 in calculator, it will still 2, not swapped wit 5.

Comment: my first green tick! *fist pump* thanks OP!